# programmatically create netTcp binding with certificates

Tags: wcf, tcp, nettcpbinding

I have a general purpose hosting service for WCF (.net v4).  It allows for multiple agents to be dropped in plug-in style with each agent having its own config file.  It was written as a service since all sites will not have IIS or WAS intalled but we can specify .net v4 and our custome service.

We have had no issues with HTTP, HTTPS or TCP (without credentials).  When we add, a certificate to the server it appears to start without an issue.  As soon as we attempt to call the servie we get a channel fault.  We wrote a small self-hosting program that uses the config file rather than programmatically creating the endpoing and it works without any issue.  We can only speculate we missed a setting but cannot identify which.

The error we get is shown below.  It appears that for some reason the client it trying to set up a dual-channel tcp connection which we did not configure in the host.

```
Protocol Type application/negotiate was sent to a service that does not support that type of upgrade.
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel.ProcessUpgradeRequest(TimeoutHelper&amp; timeoutHelper)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelListener`3.HandleAcceptComplete(TInnerChannel channel)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelListener`3.OnAcceptCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableChannelListener`3.OnAcceptCompletedStatic(IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)
System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4.&lt;CallbackGenerator&gt;b__2(AsyncCallback callback, IAsyncResult result)
System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpDuplexChannelListener.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ISessionPreambleHandler.HandleServerSessionPreamble(ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader preambleReader, ConnectionDemuxer connectionDemuxer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionOrientedTransportManager`1.OnHandleServerSessionPreamble(ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader serverSessionPreambleReader, ConnectionDemuxer connectionDemuxer)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionDemuxer.OnSessionPreambleKnown(ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader serverSessionPreambleReader)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.ContinueReading()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader.StartReading(Action`1 viaDelegate, TimeSpan receiveTimeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionDemuxer.OnDuplexConnection(IConnection connection, Action connectionDequeuedCallback, Int64 streamPosition, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionDemuxer.OnConnectionModeKnownCore(ConnectionModeReader modeReader, Boolean isCached)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionDemuxer.OnConnectionModeKnown(ConnectionModeReader modeReader)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionModeReader.Complete()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionModeReader.ReadCallback(Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.WaitCallback(Object state)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.FinishRead()
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.AsyncReadCallback(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 bytesRead)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.OverlappedContext.CompleteCallback(UInt32 error, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

CLIENT:

```
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpEndPoint_ISolutionsDataAccessorV01" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:1177/TcpService" binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetTcpEndPoint_ISolutionsDataAccessorV01"
            contract="sDAL.ISolutionsDataAccessorV01" name="NetTcpEndPoint_ISolutionsDataAccessorV01">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="abc@xyz.com" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

SERVICE:
  
    
      
    
    
      
        
          
            
            -->

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SolutionsDALServiceBehavior">
   <serviceCredentials>
     <serviceCertificate findValue="STSTestCert"
                         x509FindType="FindByIssuerName" />
   </serviceCredentials>
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <!-- <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/> -->
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```